How to get OT notes and PT notes from EPIC FHIR API
I am trying to get the PT notes and OT notes but from the document reference API (Clinical Notes, Labs, LDAs etc) but not what I wanted can anyone help with this.
I investigate all the document reference endpoints, labs, lists etc.
https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/api/FHIR/STU3/DocumentReference/e.q.BLfR29vX-T-.y0bQbKg3

https://fhir.epic.com/Specifications?api=1048
Screen Shot from epic
Tried the above but didn't get the required documents of OT notes and PT notes.
And I am able to see the progress note here but unbale to get please see the response below.
{
    "resourceType": "DocumentReference",
    "id": "e.q.BLfR29vX-T-.y0bQbKg3",
    "identifier": [
        {
            "system": "urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.0.1.7.2.727879",
            "value": "194922"
        }
    ],
    "status": "current",
    "docStatus": "final",
    "type": {
        "coding": [
            {
                "system": "http://loinc.org",
                "code": "11506-3",
                "display": "Provider-unspecified Progress note"
            },
            {
                "system": "urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.0.1.7.4.737880.5010",
                "code": "1",
                "display": "Progress Notes"
            }
        ],
        "text": "Provider-unspecified Progress note"
    },
    "class": {
        "coding": [
            {
                "system": "https://argonautproject.github.io/clinicalnotes/ValueSet-documentreference-category.html",
                "code": "clinical-notes",
                "display": "Clinical Notes"
            },
            {
                "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/CodeSystem/us-core-documentreference-category",
                "code": "clinical-note",
                "display": "Clinical Note"
            }
        ],
        "text": "Clinical Notes"
    },
    "subject": {
        "reference": "https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/api/FHIR/STU3/Patient/e63wRTbPfr1p8UW81d8Seiw3",
        "display": "Mychart, Theodore"
    },
    "created": "2018-10-26T23:04:44Z",
    "indexed": "2018-10-26T23:04:44Z",
    "author": [
        {
            "display": "Epic Sandbox, User"
        }
    ],
    "authenticator": {
        "display": "0"
    },
    "content": [
        {
            "attachment": {
                "contentType": "text/html",
                "url": "https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/api/FHIR/STU3/Binary/ejJD-7U3OqOcsHTnJnjMrDw3"
            },
            "format": {
                "system": "http://ihe.net/fhir/ValueSet/IHE.FormatCode.codesystem",
                "code": "urn:ihe:iti:xds:2017:mimeTypeSufficient",
                "display": "mimeType Sufficient"
            }
        }
    ],
    "context": {
        "encounter": {
            "reference": "https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/api/FHIR/STU3/Encounter/ecgXt3jVqNNpsXnNXZ3KljA3",
            "identifier": {
                "use": "usual",
                "system": "urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.0.1.7.3.698084.8",
                "value": "1853"
            },
            "display": "Office Visit"
        },
        "period": {
            "start": "2013-11-06T20:45:00Z"
        }
    }
}


The request shown in your question is a read call, where you are looking up a specific DocumentReference with the ID provided (e.q.BLfR29vX-T-.y0bQbKg3). It will only ever return that single DocumentReference.
If you are trying to find a series of notes for a patient, you should be making a search call with the necessary search parameters. It would look something like /DocumentReference?<param1>=<value>&<param2>=value. Epic does support searching by note type if you know the correct code(s) to use. Of course, the environment you are connecting to needs to have a patient with OT and PT notes available for those to be retrieved.

Yes, I also had tried this search as well but in that also there is no any PT and OT notes for which I am looking for. Here, you have mentioned about the codes can you direct me from where I can get those codes.

The exact list of codes will vary per environment you are connecting to. For the Epic on FHIR sandbox that you are connecting to in your example, there isn't a published list of codes. You could try emailing open@epic.com to see if they are able to share the list or the specific ones for OT/PT and if they can point you to any patients with those notes available.
